# foreach variables into array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

Here is the code I'm using to upload Multiple Photos with the HTML5  tag.

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
    $rand_file_name = rand(1,1000000);
    if ($_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/png" || $_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/JPEG" || $_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/GIF" || $_FILES['files']['type'][$key] == "image/PNG") {
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$key] < 512000){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../../../assets/users/$user_id/photos/$browser_album_id/$rand_file_name.jpg");
            $photo_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $photo_name = str_replace(".jpg", "", $photo_name);
            $photo_name = str_replace(".png", "", $photo_name);
            $photo_name = str_replace(".gif", "", $photo_name);
            $insert_database = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo_album_photos (random_photo_name,belonging_album_id,photo_name) VALUES ('$rand_file_name','$browser_album_id','$photo_name')");
            $num_files_added++;
        }
    }
}
```

The **$num_files_added** will count how many files were added.

what I would like to achieve is to gather the **$rand_file_name**(s) into an array. Each image is given a random name, so one image could be 812532.jpg and the next maybe 246546.jpg.

I would like to insert the file names into the database an array. So the above examples would be in an array. e.g. **array(812532,246546);**

Of course, I don't want anyone to code this straight up for me, just help and guidance! :)

Comment: It's enough for what you are looking ->  $arr_files[] = $rand_file_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `foreach`, introduce a variable `$file_names = array();` as a blank array

and in the foreach loop, try this :

```
$file_names[] = $rand_file_name;
```

Then, you can access the array that will be stored in the `$file_names` variable. :)

**To make them into a comma separated string**

Introduce `$file_names = ''` before the foreach loop.

Then in the loop, do this :

```
$file_names .= $rand_file_name . ',';
```

And after closing the foreach loop, this :

```
$file_names = substr($file_names,0,-1);
```

Comment: When I echo this out, is it supposed to say array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array. To see the array values, do a `print_r($file_names)`

Comment: what I want it to say in the database is **812532,246546**. How would I go about that?

Comment: In that case, you can add the file names to a string, instead of an array. See the edited post please

Comment: Hate to sound stupid, but where's the edited post? I look at your post above but it looks the same?

Comment: All I get is the number of how many files were uploaded, onto the page?

Comment: Sorry, edited the post again. Check this, and echo $file_names to see what it outputs.

Comment: But then when I remove the `$file_names = substr($file_names,0,1);` line it displays them, but with a comma on the end?

Comment: to make them into a comma separated string, we should be using implode()! So much cleaner.

Comment: @Julien for the array, yes :)

Comment: `join(', ', $file_names)` is much cleaner. No need to loop.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can append to an array by not specifying its index.

For example, look at this loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $a[] = "file$i";
}
```

Each time the loop executes, the array `$a` will contain a new element like `file1`, `file2`, `file3`...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

$rand_file_names = array();

$rand_file_names[] = $rand_file_name;

I wouldn't recommend storing $rand_file_names as `array(812532,246546)` in the database though. If that's what you are looking for you should try [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).